# How to pass multiple variables from funtion to jquery attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

> This question is related to [How to pass multiple variables from function to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457125/how-to-pass-multiple-variables-from-function-to-function)

So in the link above you might have seen how you can pass a variable(or mutiple) from function to function, but **what if you want to pass it from a regular js function into the jquery `.attr()` value?**

That might sound strange as a statement, that's why I'll include an example.

```js
$(function() {

  function definingVars() {
    var Value = "Sucess with the value";
    var Id = successWithTheId;
    var Class = sucessWithTheClass;
    return [Value, Id, Class];
  }

  $("input").attr({
    //  var df = definingVars();  Incorrect syntax!!!
    value: df.Value,
    id: df.Id,
    class: df.Class
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="noSucessWithTheId" class="noSucessWithTheClass" value="No sucess with the value">
```

But as you can see the line that should aloud the `attr` jquery function to capture the values from `definingVars()` is clearly commented as that is not the correct syntax.

But how can you still pass on those variables?

That is my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to pass multiple properties to `.attr()`, for which we uses an object with key/value pair.

So what you can do is to return an object from `definingVars` and pass the value returned by `definingVars` as the argument to `attr()` like

```js
$(function() {

  function definingVars() {
    var Value = "Sucess with the value";
    var Id = successWithTheId;
    var Class = sucessWithTheClass;
    
    return {
      value: Value,
      id: Id,
      class: Class
    };
  }

  $("input").attr(definingVars())

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna stick with the current structure of `definingVars()`, then Just call directly the function if you wanted :

```
$("input").attr({
 value: definingVars()[0],
 id: definingVars()[1],
 class: definingVars()[2]
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/pbp5ov3x/)

Comment: Probably not great to call the method three times

Comment: @RobbieAverill Yes, that true. It just an alternative if OP want stick the current structure of function instead.